# Difference between system printers and app printers

Tags: printing, libreoffice, 23.10, gnome-text-editor

Is there a difference between the system printers within Ubuntu and the printers listed in applications such as LibreOffice or Gnome Text Editor?

I have 3 printers within my network. Three are *discovered* from within the system printers window and another three printers are visible within i.e. LibreOffice Writer and Gnome Text Editor.

[image]

Why are the non-configured printers showing up within the apps?